# How to make sure HBase Java client is using the hbase-site.xml

Tags: hbase

Versions:
Hadoop: 2.0.0-cdh4.3.1
HBase: 0.94.6-cdh4.3.1

I am running cloudera quick start vm, Here is my little remote HBase Java client(HbaseClient.java), all it does is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    HTable table = new HTable(config, "s1");
    System.out.println(table.getTableName());
}
```

When I run my java client, I get this error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
2013-08-25 00:01:56.684 java[39082:1703] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for s1,,99999999999999 after 10 tries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:980)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:885)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:987)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:846)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:170)
    at com.***************.api.HBaseClient.main(HBaseClient.java:24)
```

I debugged through the code, it's hard to find whether the client is using my hbase-site.xml in resources folder or not. I even put wrong format content in hbase-site.xml, Java client is getting the same error. So I think it's not using it. Isn't resources folder part of the CLASSPATH? Is there any way to check if the hbase-site.xml gets used, if not used, how to get my client to use it.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First put your configuration files,meaning core-site.xml hbase-site.xml hdfs-site.xml,  in src/main/resources et make this a source folder (under eclipse right click on the folder -> Build Path -> Use as source folder)
Then try this code

```
public class HbaseConfig {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HbaseConfig.class);
    public static org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration getHHConfig() {
        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        InputStream confResourceAsInputStream = conf.getConfResourceAsInputStream("hbase-site.xml");
        int available = 0;
        try {
            available = confResourceAsInputStream.available();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //for debug purpose
            LOG.debug("configuration files not found locally");
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(confResourceAsInputStream);
        }
        if (available == 0 ) {
            conf = new Configuration();
            conf.addResource("core-site.xml");
            conf.addResource("hbase-site.xml");
            conf.addResource("hdfs-site.xml");
        }
        return conf;
    }
}
```

Finally in your code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Configuration config = HbaseConfig.getHHConfig();
        HTable table = new HTable(config, "s1");
        System.out.println(table.getTableName());
}
```

Comment: if (available == 0 )  why zero (0)??

Comment: No reason really

Answer (score 1):

All you have to make sure is that the *site.xml files are copied from your hadoop instance and is made available in your eclipse classpath. Just add the folder which contains the xmls as a source folder and that should be enough.